# Python Windows 10 Import from Different Directory

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to import the file File.py file from a specific directory, C:\MyPythonFiles. This is what I tried(among several other different attempts):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("c:\MyPythonFiles")
import File.py
```

Can someone please tell me how to import File.py from the diretory C:\MyPythonFiles ?
[image]

Removing the .py so that its 'import File' didn't work either:
[image]

[UPDATE]

So in my File.py, I had an import for a file that I did not include in c:\MyPythonFiles, so that was a huge problem.

I edited File.py so it only has one function, printHello(). The script works, but PyCharm still does not recognize 'File' for import. I can still use the line File.printHello(), but it's annoying since PyCharm is not autofilling the functions for 'import File'. Any ideas on how to solve this new problem?

[image]

[UPDATE]
I think @alex answered the original question, and my PyCharm issue should be a seperate question. Thanks for the help @alex!

Comment: The code in the picture differs from the code you have posted...

Comment: '\','/', it doesn't make a difference. I still get the same error. Same thing with " or '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("c:\\MyPythonFiles")
import File
```

or

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"c:\MyPythonFiles")
import File
```

or

```
import sys
sys.path.append("c:/MyPythonFiles")
import File
```

1.Don't need ".py"

2.path link error

[Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work for me either. 'import File' is still giving me an error.